# Javascript error when using Exp:resso Store in a Safecracker entry form

Tags: expresso-store, safecracker

EE 2.5.5, 
Exp:resso Store 1.6.3

The Store Product Details field works fine in the Control Panel, but when using it in a SafeCracker form, I get the following javascript error (from themes/thirdparty/store/cp.min.js):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'
```

Here's the template code I'm using:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="signups" entry_id="18" return="foobar" }
    {field:product_details}
{/exp:safecracker}
```

Is there anything else I should be doing to get Store to work with SafeCracker?

Comment: We need more information to help you. What version of EE, Store, calendar, ect. Also your safecracker template code with the resulting errors

Comment: Hi Steve - I've rewritten your question so you can get a better idea of a concise, specific question which is easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Store introduced by newer versions of EE and/or SafeCracker. We will have a fix out for it shortly.

In the meantime, you can fix it yourself fairly easily by opening `ft.store.php`, and around line 37, replace this line:

```
$this->EE->cp->add_js_script(array('ui' => 'datepicker'));
```

with this:

```
$this->EE->cp->add_js_script(array('ui' => array('datepicker', 'sortable')));
```

That will tell SafeCracker that it needs to load the jQuery UI Sortable library, which is included by default in the EE control panel (hence why it is working fine for you in the CP).

Comment: Thanks. But in the time it took for me to get schooled in proper customer etiquette, and for someone to actually take the time to reproduce the problem, and for an official service channel response, I've managed to find your bug and fix it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Are you including your own version of jQuery by chance? This error looks like store is looking for jQuery UI Sortable and it's not present on the jQuery object, which can happen if: you load jQuery, plugins, then load jQuery again, thus overriding the original.

You can disable safecracker's auto jQuery load: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/#include-jquery

Comment: Thank you. No sir. Totally clean install. No other modules. None of my own jQuery in the template head. Nothing.